# Django==2.1 , setting DEBUG to False results in 500 server error

Tags: django, django-deployment

I have the following `settings.py` file for my django project:

```
"""

Django settings for framework project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '**************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'graphene_django',
    'graphql_jwt.refresh_token.apps.RefreshTokenConfig',
    'django_filters',
    'sass_processor',
    'hamlpy',
    'ckeditor',
    'easy_select2',
    'members',
    'activity',
    'blog',
    'pages',
    'status',
    'gsoc'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'framework.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': (
                'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyFilesystemLoader',
                'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyAppDirectoriesLoader',
            ),
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'framework.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'framework.schema.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    ],
}
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    'JWT_ALLOW_ARGUMENT': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=7),
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)

SASS_PROCESSOR_ENABLED = True
SASS_PROCESSOR_AUTO_INCLUDE = True
SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = 'static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]

try:
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
except ImportError:
    found = False
```

I wanted to add custom 404 and 500 error pages, for which I set DEBUG = False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"].
But when I run the local server and view the website, I get `500 server error` for every page.
However, the site works perfectly when DEBUG = True.
How do I correct this issue?
Similar question has been asked before, but the answers are old for the version of django.

Comment: does it only fail on the live server or dev server? could you post an error log?

Comment: @ohlr It fails in the development server. The question has been asked before but it is 6 years old.

Comment: @ohlr I don't have an error log, let me try make one.

Comment: @ohlr running `python manage.py collectstatic` solved the issue.